# Sample observations per group without replacement in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica, sampling

Using the provided table I would like to sample let's say 2 users per day so that users assigned to the two days are different. Of course the problem I have is more sophisticated, but this simple example gives the idea.

```
drop table if exists test; 

create table test (
user_id int,
day_of_week int);

insert into test values (1, 1);
insert into test values (1, 2);
insert into test values (2, 1);
insert into test values (2, 2);
insert into test values (3, 1);
insert into test values (3, 2);
insert into test values (4, 1);
insert into test values (4, 2);
insert into test values (5, 1);
insert into test values (5, 2);
insert into test values (6, 1);
insert into test values (6, 2);
```

The expected results would look like this:

```
create table results (
user_id int,
day_of_week int);

insert into results values (1, 1);
insert into results values (2, 1);
insert into results values (3, 2);
insert into results values (6, 2);
```

Comment: Can you post what your expected results are, its not clear what's being asked.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I updated and tagged the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  Here is an example . . . although the details do depend on your database (functions for random numbers vary by database):

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by day_of_week order by random()) as seqnum
      from test t
     ) t 
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works :) One more question, do you know how to make it work if I wanted to make the number of observations to sample vary by day? I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @abu . . . Do not edit the question.  Ask another question!  This one is answered.

Comment: The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665786/sampling-without-replacement-with-a-different-sample-size-per-group-in-sql).